# Hadoop missing input which is present in HDFS

Tags: hadoop

Evening All,

I'm trying to run a training sample on Hadoop mapreduce, but am receiving an error that the input path does not exist.

```
16/09/26 05:56:45 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : Input path does not exist: hdfs://bigtop1.vagrant:8020/training
```

However, looking inside the hdfs directory, it's clear that the "training" folder is present.

```
[vagrant@bigtop1 code]$ hadoop fs -ls
Found 3 items
drwx------   - vagrant hadoop          0 2016-09-26 05:47 .staging
drwxr-xr-x   - vagrant hadoop          0 2016-09-26 04:28 hw2
drwxr-xr-x   - vagrant hadoop          0 2016-09-26 04:14 training
```

Using HDFS commands:

```
[vagrant@bigtop1 code]$ hdfs dfs -ls training
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant hadoop          0 2016-09-26 04:14 training/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 vagrant hadoop    3311720 2016-09-26 04:14 training/part-r-00000
```

Does anyone know of a possible reason that Hadoop would be missing data that is clearly present?

Invocation Below, had to hide one input (-f):

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -D mapreduce.job.reduces=5 -files lr -mapper "python lr/mapper.py -n 5 -r 0.4" -reducer "python lr/reducer.py -e 0.1 -c 0.0 -f ####" -input /training/ -output /models
```

Comment: you need to  specify from -input /training/ to  -input training/ [only need to remove the "/" from input file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the input parameter as something like this.

From

```
-input /training/
```

To

```
-input training/
```

Comment: Appreciate the response Bhavesh, this resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$ hadoop fs -ls` it shows you the data in the current users home directory.

Are you sure the path to your data isnt `/user/vagrant/`?

If the `training` directory isn't present when you run `$ hadoop fs -ls /` then you have the path wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the input parameter as something like this.

```
-input hdfs://<machinename>/user/vagrant/training/
```